# Socket issue when include mutex C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, mutex

I write a program, that should **create a server** using a socket in a extra thread. This works **well**, **until** I `#include <mutex>` to my application. But I need to include mutex for another function (not in the example here).

When I include mutex, I get this error when calling `bind` (marked in code):

> error C2440: '=': cannot convert 'std::_Bind' to 'long' in (PATH_TO_PROJECT_LINE_WHERE_BIND_IS_CALLED)

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#include <cstdio>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <process.h>
#include <mutex> //if I do not include mutex, everything works


using namespace std;






unsigned int __stdcall threadCreateServer(void*data){

    long res;

    WSADATA wsaData;

    res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData);
    if (res == 0){
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "WSAStartup successful" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "Error WSAStartup" << endl;
        return -201;
    }

    SOCKET slisten, client;

    slisten = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (slisten != INVALID_SOCKET){
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "Socket() successful" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "error Socket" << endl;
        return -202;
    }


    sockaddr_in info;
    info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    info.sin_port = htons(54126);

    res = bind(slisten, (struct sockaddr*)&info, sizeof(info)); //ERROR HERE
    if (res != SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "bind successful" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "ERROR bind" << endl;
        return -203;
    }

    res = listen(slisten, 1); 
    if (res != SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "Listen successful" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "Listen error" << endl;
        return -204;
    }
    sockaddr_in clientinfo;
    int clientinfolen = sizeof(clientinfo);

    cout << endl << "~~~~~~~~~" << endl << "[CreateServer] " << "Please connect a client to " << inet_ntoa(info.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(info.sin_port) << endl << "~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
    client = accept(slisten, (struct sockaddr*)&clientinfo, &clientinfolen);
    if (client != SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "Client accepted " << inet_ntoa(clientinfo.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(clientinfo.sin_port) << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "[CreateServer] " << "ERROR client not accepted" << endl;
    }


}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    HANDLE handleThreadCreateServer=(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0,0,&threadCreateServer,0,0,0);

    WaitForSingleObject(handleThreadCreateServer, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(handleThreadCreateServer);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Conflicting functions? Have you already tried removing the `using namespace std;`

Comment: This works. Is there a way to use the namespace but avoid this problem? My application is more than 1000 code lines long, so that removing `using namespace std`would be very pesky.

Comment: Try adding `using std::string;` ... instead

Comment: That's why every C++ FAQ tells you not to blindly import things from any namespace. I'm pretty sure you could also call `::bind()` explicitly to disambiguate between the imported symbol and the global one.

Comment: Using `::bind()` is the correct solution in this example to require the least amount of code change. But removing the `using namespace std` statement would be the *preferred* solution in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in a comment, I cannot do `using namespace std`, because there would be conflicting functions when including `mutex`.
For everyone, who will have this problem, too:

```
//to not using namespace std, but:
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
```

For every other function that isn't used until now, a similar line has to be added. There is not possibllity of using the namespace std and "unusing" std::mutex.

Comment: Note that you can scope `using` statements. So you can put `using namespace std` at the beginning of every function that doesn't need mutex. It would probably be best to just put the mutex code in a small separate though to limit confusion.

Comment: Thank you! That is a great "compromise"